# AWS CLI failed to display response

Tags: amazon-web-services, terminal, aws-cli

I am using `aws-cli version 2.8.8`.

Connecting to AWS using LDAP and it is successful.

If I run command `aws s3 ls` then I get the results.

However when I try run command `aws dynamodb list-tables` nothing get displayed. Same for `aws ec2 describe-instances` no response.

When I run same command in debug mode I can see exception in `awscli.clidriver` file:

Exception details

```
2022-11-03 12:27:55,762 - MainThread - awscli.clidriver - DEBUG - Exception caught in main()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "awscli/clidriver.py", line 458, in main
  File "awscli/clidriver.py", line 593, in __call__
  File "awscli/clidriver.py", line 769, in __call__
```

My team members uses the same cli version and account and then can access to all data. The issue is with my Mac terminal.

I tried searching for this issue online but no one has reported it. This could be with my terminal but I am not able to identify root cause.

Comment: If there was no error displayed in normal (non-debug) mode, then I wouldn't be worried. Were you perhaps querying the wrong region? Try `aws ec2 describe-instances --region us-west-2` (or whatever your normal region is). You can set your **default region** with `aws configure`.

Comment: The data is in region us-west-2. In ~aws.credentials I can see the same region. As well as can see same when I run aws configure. 
Still I am not getting response. 
When I run the command without --debug, nothing get displayed.

Comment: Able to solve the issue, there was extra parameter output in aws config file which was causing to output the response in cli

Comment: Glad to hear you fixed it! If you think this will be useful for future readers, please add an Answer. (Yes, you can answer your own question.) Or, if you don't think it will be useful, feel free to Delete this question.